# Question kept getting deleted even after I made it CW

Tags: support, specific-question, subjective, deleted-questions, undelete

[Premature optimization is the root of all evil, but can it ever be too late?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537760/)

There were some arguments whether or not it should've been CW and what CW really means etc, I stopped caring about that so I made it CW, and it still kept getting deleted anyway.

I don't care if it's opened anymore but can I at least keep it alive just for myself? Feel free to lock it or whatever.

---

*Update*: Okay, so after many UNDELETES, and enough votes to get it OPENED, now it's DELETED and LOCKED, and I lost 100 rep pts. Would anyone explain what went wrong here?

Comment: Why would this be closed for "Too localized"? Of course it's localized, that's why I tagged it `[support]` and `[specific question]`.

Comment: This question should not be closed as too localized. SO users are specifically encouraged to ask questions about closed/deleted questions on meta. It helps build an understanding of "the rules".

Comment: Thanks for your support guys, question is re-undeleted for now. I hope it won't get re-re-deleted.

Comment: Moderators: feel free to tag `[status-completed]`; I tried to do it myself out of courtesy but wasn't authorized to (apparently).

Comment: Have this for your own perusal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta/47640#47640

Comment: OK, it got re-re-deleted again, but for some reason I only needed 1 vote from myself to re-re-undelete it.

Comment: THIS IS GETTING RIDICULOUS http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2537760/revisions

Comment: @pol: thanks for pointing that bug out.

Comment: See the discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49150/user-can-undelete-own-question-with-one-vote-closed) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49159/gaming-the-system-with-spam-flags).

Comment: What is answer to that question? It says 404 now.

Comment: @Vi: there's a lot of good answers there, I thought, but too bad you can't see it... until you become a 10K-er. So there's your motivation: start earning those reps!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a discussion question, rather than a question about a specific programming problem.  Such questions are really not what Stack Overflow is about.  You could argue that the question is about optimizing programs, but that is at best a *general* programming problem.  So again - not really a good fit for Stack Overflow.

That said, this is enforced in such a way that exceptions can be made for the occasional off-topic question.  If a question is good enough the community might to decide to leave it alone, even if it breaks a rule or two.  But such exceptions are rare, and akin to winning the lottery.  There are even "prizes", in that a well-received discussion question is likely to earn a badge or two.  But also like the lottery, there's no point in whining when you don't win.  Also like the lottery, I'd hope that most here are smart enough not to play.

Of course, I've said all this before.  For this particular instance, I'll add that personally I'm not inclined to vote to close any question that's already received at least 10 votes, as your question did.  But neither will I vote to re-open a question that's so obviously subjective.

Also, a few comments on Community Wiki:  Community Wiki questions have the *side effect* that they don't accrue reputation.  This is intentional; if everyone is supposed to edit and contribute to the post, why should the reputation go to one person?  Moreover, the community has also decided it does not want users accruing reputation for discussion and other less-technical posts.  Reputation on Stack Overflow should be indicator of your technical contribution rather than the popularity contest that would result from giving lots of rep for discussion posts.  The result is that you are encouraged to mark subjective posts as community wiki, even if you'd rather claim more direct ownership.  This doesn't guarantee a discussion question will stay open, but it does help your chances.

Comment: +1 for that excellent lottery analogy.

Comment: @Joel: I'll admit that reps and badges are nice, but prem-op issues are a big deal for me (the last part of the question suggests some of my own personal struggle with it). I wasn't playing lottery with this one; this question means a lot to me.

Comment: @poly - That's okay, but then you need to re-think the question in terms of a specific optimization.  I can answer your question right here, though: the correct thing to do is use a profiler to analyze your running code to find out where the real bottlenecks are, and then focus your time there.

Answer (score 5):

I don't mind it being closed, but I do have a problem with people actually deleting a question that has gotten signficant upvotes.  I've voted to "undelete" it and I would encourage others to do so as well.

Comment: I agree, so +1!

Comment: If I could vote to 'close permanently' without deleting, I would (in some cases). If I could vote to 'retain without rep', I would (in some cases). Absent those, I vote to delete. Cause otherwise, they reopen and the rep farming continues unabated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are a very large number of users who do not understand what Community Wiki is for, and who badger question authors into making their questions CW when in reality the question should simply be (and usually will be) closed.  The CW argument just adds noise.  CW is not for "discussion" questions, it is an assertion that you don't "own" the question/answer, and allows lower-rep users to edit it.

Questions closed for any reason other than a duplicate are generally also deleted by the 10k+ users, to prevent them from being reopened later and also to prevent them from showing up in the search results.

Unfortunately, this also means that you can't view your own question.  It would be nice if authors could still see their own deleted questions, but at this point, you'll just have to wait until you've got 10k yourself. :)

Edit: Actually, I see that you already *do* have 10k on Stack Overflow, so you can still view the question if you bookmark it; it just won't show up on your profile or in a search.

Comment: Like I said, though, I don't care about the CW aspect anymore. I want the question undeleted, and locked if mods feel compelled to. I like the question, I want other people (i.e. even non-member) to be able to read it, and yes I would also like to keep the 11 votes I got from it (pre-CW).

Comment: there are lots of people who have decided that, whatever CW officially means, it represents a tolerable middle ground between close+delete versus watching rep pile up for popularity. The Management has declined to address this with either a stronger stance against subjective questions or some other mechanism, so CW it is.

Comment: @bmargulies: All it takes is a few people spreading false/misleading information; other people latch on to it and the cycle continues and expands indefinitely.  It's not up to The Management to address this, it's up to The Community, i.e. us, and everybody here needs to do their part to keep the site from becoming a dumping ground for every random thought.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this question does not belong on SO. However, it got enough attention that I don't think it should have been deleted. I've voted to undelete, but two more 10K users will need to agree with me.

If you just want a copy of everything that was there, let me know and I'll paste it into an answer here for you.