# User can undelete own question with one vote

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the owner of a question get it undeleted with his vote alone? and also could be undelete many times?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/can-the-owner-of-a-question-get-it-undeleted-with-his-vote-alone-and-also-could)

Through [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48980/question-kept-getting-deleted-even-after-i-made-it-cw), I found out about [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2537760/revisions), that the OP keeps undeleting with merely **one vote**.

Comment: No problem.  Looking at the history, lots of people have voted to keep that question around.  I'm not sure if killing it with my one mod vote is right, so I'm waiting to see what happens.  If it gets deleted again, I'll lock it. (Or, I guess if it stays around long enough I'll lock it in its current state.)

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537760/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil-but-can-it-ever-be-too-late is a really good question, and covers ground not adequately covered by the duplicates; namely that the phrase, "Premature Optimization is the root of all evil" is widely misquoted by people who don't understand what it really means, and is always missing the remainder of the quote that gives it its true meaning. I'm surprised that the community was so adamant about getting it deleted; apparently it has become a religious issue.

Comment: I don't understand -- how does one do this?

Comment: @Evan, because 10k+ users can see deleted questions, and have ability to undelete, for more info, see faq :-)

Comment: An interesting point of fact: Apparently the naysayers got their way by **flagging the question as spam.** That is what caused the *Deleted by Community* and *Locked by Community* entries in the edit history.

Comment: @Robert: I didn't delete, merely vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it doesn't seem to fit the standard set of operational guidelines.

If I delete my own question I should then be able to un-delete with fair ease. However, this is not the case. The question is voted by multiple users to delete - therefore, an equal (if not greater) number of votes should be required to un-delete.

This appears to be too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Its by-design, because of upvotes and answers counts according to Jeff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/can-the-owner-of-a-question-get-it-undeleted-with-his-vote-alone-and-also-could), and yes, I voted to closed as duplicate.

<sub>**Note**: In my case, I have deleted myself instead of keep undeleting it.</sub>