# Educating people who misuse flags regularly

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators, 10k-tools

These posts all have spam flags on SO right now (some more than one):

- [PostgreSQL "DESCRIBE TABLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table/109331#109331)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526311/baby-names-for-programmers-closed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526311/baby-names-for-programmers/3526344#3526344
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523425/help-me-to-print-star-pattern-as-follows-closed

I have no idea what's going on with the Postgres one, but I assume the baby names ones were flagged as being NaRQ, and the star pattern one for being homework. It's unclear if people are flagging because they don't understand what spam flags are actually for, or intentionally misusing them because they don't like the post. If it's the former, is there any way they could ever realize they're using flags wrong? If it's the latter, are there any repercussions?

I don't think there's any way to automatically detect it; mods would have to notice that the same people keep flagging posts that don't actually warrant flags and e-mail them directly, which I'm guessing doesn't happen a lot ([this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/what-could-be-done-to-stop-the-misuse-of-the-spam-and-offensive-flags/33283#33283) indicates some mods regularly clear invalid flags, but that doesn't help with stopping people from using them wrong in the first place). Allowing 10k users to [disagree with flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49245/allow-10k-users-to-disagree-with-spam-offensive-flags) would be sufficient; the system could track if the same user is disagreed with multiple times and alert mods, but that system doesn't exist yet

Of course, all this assumes it's the same people regularly misusing flags; if it's actually different people every time this might not be worth dealing with

Comment: To repeat my [previous answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/what-could-be-done-to-stop-the-misuse-of-the-spam-and-offensive-flags/33267#33267): meh.

Comment: @Shog9 I do pretty regularly flag already-flagged posts for mod attention; particularly if they were flagged as being questions posted as answers (which seems to happen a lot). I'm more interested in stopping people from intentionally abusing flags as an extra way to downvote a post; flags seem to be a void in the checks and balances of the site; you need almost no rep to flag, it doesn't cost any rep like downvoting, and nothing bad happens if you flag posts at random for no reason

Comment: well, that's why Jon B's answer is probably the best... Since the flags "evaporate" after time, there's not a lot of harm anyone can do with them on their own. As for nothing bad happening... I know of one user who is banned for a very long time for over-using them.

Comment: this post currently has an offensive flag for some reason...

Answer (score 3):

You bring up a good point.

Unfortunately the downside of a community moderated website is that if a person really hates a post they will do anything in their power to "harm" it. For example, if someone posts a question that doesn't fit any of the close reasons (not even "noise") some people will try (sometimes successfully) to close it as "too localized" or similar, even if they are fully aware that it's not a valid close reason.

The same happens - many times more often - with flags. If someone really hates an answer, since they can't "close" it, the only thing they can do to "harm" it is flagging. There are three types of flags:

- Spam. This one [according to official policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56223/has-there-been-an-uptick-in-spam-votes-against-established-questions/56224#56224) should be used **only** in case advertisements that are against the rules. This is probably the most misused flag, maybe perhaps of the fact that spam is a very overloaded term. Jeff once confirmed here on meta that "spam" is used with the meaning of not permitted advertisement (too lazy to dig up the post), but many people didn't read that post, and probably some decided to ignore it.
- Offensive. The definition of offensive is sometimes stretched too, for example someone once said they flagged an answer because the idea contained within was "offensive to the spirit of the community", which I think is a pretty ridiculous stretch.
- Flag for mod attention. This one doesn't cause the post to be auto deleted, and is also - as the name implies - constantly checked by moderators, so it's not abused.

Answer (score 2):

## When To Flag

- **Spam**: When a post is *mass-targeted*. This means advertisements or bot posts.
- **Offensive**: Should be considered the general sense. This should be things that offend you *as a human being* not things that offend you *as a programmer*. This **excludes** matters of ethics.*
- **Flag for mod attention**: This should be used for cases that are *exceptional*. This should be largely based on negative user behaviour.

### Spam

> When a post is *mass-targeted*. This means advertisements or bot posts.

If a user is "trolling", that is, trying to start flamewars or elicit an emotional response. This is **not** spam. It is not appropriate, but it is highly targeted, and therefore the *user* needs to be brought to attention and dealt with by moderators.

Flagging for spam is for posts which you believe are **not** hand crafted, but rather *mass produced*. If you want to call it spam, but it doesn't meet those criteria, consider flagging for a moderator. If it doesn't warrant a 'flag for moderator', then don't flag it at all.

### Offensive:

> Should be considered the general sense. This should be things that offend you *as a human being* not things that offend you *as a programmer*. This **excludes** matters of ethics.*

Swearing, Racism, Sexism, vile abuse upon users, or groups. These are all examples of offensive. Advocating the use of "GOTO" is *not*.

Ethics, that is practices which you consider unethical, are **not** offensive either. If a user wants to ask how to view what websites his employees are using, this would offend me *as an employee* but it is not the *technical question* that is offensive.  If you consider this particular instance to be specially egregious, then flag for moderator attention. If it doesn't warrant a 'flag for moderator', then don't flag it at all.

### Flag for mod attention

> This should be used for cases that are exceptional. This should be largely based on negative user behaviour.

This should **not** be used for cases where you do not have the rights to accomplish your purpose. If it needs to be re-tagged, edited or closed, **do not** flag for moderator attention. There is a reason why these functions have been delegated to the community, and a reason why the reputation thresholds were set where they were. Allow the *community* the chance to deal with these.

In cases where the community is conflicted or unable to provide appropriate responses (locking, deleting, banning) in *those* cases you should flag for moderator attention.

Additionally, issues like merging two questions, trolling behaviour, comment-answers. These are all things which should be flagged for the moderators, because there are no regular tools to deal with these situations.

Comment: Flag for mod if they spot: a comment-answer; questions that need closing in a community that doesn't have the velocity of 3k yet to close by votes.

Comment: @random: by "community" do you mean SO *niche*, or a separate site? I'm making the assumption that we're talking about an established or semi-established community. I'll leave it to rcarataino to talk about how to *create* and *build* a community.

Comment: If I manually type "hey, you should try my product at [url]" doesn't that count as spam even though it *is* hand crafted? (Assume I'm not adding value to the post - I'm just begging people to buy my stuff).

Comment: Also, I disagree with your description of flagging for mod attention. This has been encouraged over and over again as a way to get help from mods for any reason. I've never heard a diamond mod or Jeff or anyone else say "stop flagging so much stuff for attention!".

Comment: @Jon B: There has been discussion of that before. Basically, if you are writing "Hey you should try my product" and it is a *relevant*, *useful*, *pertinent* product. Then it **is not** spam. If they type that on *every* question that has the right tag, then it would be considered "mass produced", and be included in the Spam flag.

Comment: @devinb I'm responding to your "hand crafted" language. I think we've seen lots of spam that's clearly spam but still "hand crafted". You might consider revising your post to elaborate on that (did I really just suggest that?)

Comment: @Jon B: Currently, there are enough moderators to easily handle all the flags. However, this doesn't mean that we should flag *more*. Or that *anything* should be flagged for mods. There are still guidelines. The mods have just generally said "when in doubt, flag for mod attention" which is what I said in both the Offensive and Spam sections.

Comment: @devinb - *"This should be used for cases that are exceptional"* this is a lot more restrictive than *"when in doubt, flag for mod attention"*. I think we're in agreement here, in general, but I think your wording is too tight.

Comment: @Jon B: I'm trying to think of a way to succinctly say "Situations which are not covered by Spam,Offensive, or not-having-enough-reputation" Except that it isn't restrictive or prescriptive *enough*. Because it doesn't prescribe when you *should*, only when you *shouldn't*.

Comment: @devinb - I think "when in doubt" sums it up nicely. If you want assistance from a moderator for something other than [what you mentioned], then flag for mod attention.

Comment: @Jon B: But flag for mod isn't a replacement for Meta. When in doubt, go to meta. When there is action to be taken, and no amount of rep can allow you to do it, or you see dangerous behaviour. Flag for mod. But "when in doubt" is *far* too permissive to be the general rule.

Comment: @devinb - as you mentioned, the mods have said "when in doubt". I don't think we need to try to override that. If they feel the flag for attention feature is being abused, they can say so.

Comment: @Jon B: Abuse is different from annoyance. This *is* the reason that flags are overused in general. People are using "spam" when they think a user posts too much, and "offensive" when they don't like their ideas. Anyway. I'm still looking for the right words. I'll let you know when I've found them.

Comment: "If you have a concern about a post that isn't covered by [one of the other tools], you can discuss it on meta, or flag it for moderator attention".

Comment: Stop coddling the moderators, @devinb. If they *really* wanted fewer flags, they'd just start boxing people flagging. I'm flagging your answer because it needs revisin'...

Comment: If a user wants to flag for mod attention on retag, edit or closing, they're fine to do so.

Comment: @Shog9: Raising flags is not really something that can be "abused" in the relevant sense. It is something that can be 'overused'. I'm not trying to coddle the moderators. I'm trying to suggest that they should be doing the *moderator* job, and not the *janitor* job.

Comment: @random I think that the rep thresholds were created for a reason. Obviously you and the other moderators are all incredibly giving and helpful people, and the fact that you are perfectly *willing* to do those things doesn't change the fact that it isn't what you are there for. You can ask a police officer for directions, yes, but the *purpose* of an officer isn't giving directions, it is to do all the things that regular citizens *can't*. That's my perspective at least.

Comment: There really isn't that much of a difference between janitor and moderator job. Flagging for mod should help lower rep users get a feel in how the community breathes and what kinds of actions are good.

Comment: @devinb: I'm not saying they need to snap to attention and do whatever some user types into that box - I'm saying there's nothing wrong with calling their attention to things that might benefit from it. While you sit there and agonize over whether or not the problem at hand is *worthy of moderator attention*, moderators are blithely clearing flags they don't care about and moving on. Remember: there's no way to flag for a *non-moderator* to come and edit/close/retag... If you feel something needs to be done and you can't do it, mod-flagging ain't a bad reflex.

Comment: I think that spam flags remain appropriate for lovingly, hand-crafted,  unresponsive advertisements. Though if there was a community consensus to just downvote them, I would live with it.

Comment: @Rosinante, I'm sure that the first one was lovingly handcrafted. I simply meant that once they start mass-producing the messages, or publishing "unresponsive" messages (that don't relate to the topic at hand) that's spam.

Comment: @random, But there's no dialog. They flag for a re-tag. If you choose not to do it, they have no idea that they were wrong or right. They only know if you *do* retag it.

Comment: @JonB: "I've never heard a diamond mod or Jeff or anyone else say "stop flagging so much stuff for attention!"" -- indeed, and some of these people have even been handed diamond mod status.

Comment: @Shog9: What i'm considering is scalability. Mods need to (at the very least) *read* any question that they are flagged to, regardless of whether or not it is purposeful or not. So my 30 seconds lost in deciding whether or not to flag for a mod, could translate to 30 * 5000 per mod, if every user decides to start flagging every time they see a typo. Obviously they don't all do that, and that's why the system works. But when we're attempting to *codify* the correct behaviour, we need to make sure that it isn't something negative.

Comment: @devinb: your definition of spam is way way too tight (and this has been discussed before) -- it doesn't just mean mass-advertisement, and it isn't even restricted to any kind of advertisement. It can also include *inappropriate or misplaced posts*, e.g. answers which should be comments, or answers which are nothing but a regurgitation of information from elsewhere (e.g. a blatant plagiarazation of another post, or a post consisting of nothing but a link).

Comment: @Ether I disagree. Do you have a link to support your version? I don't have a link to support mine, but I'm proffering it as what (I feel) the definition should be.

Comment: @devinb: if there are 5000 retag flags per day, that would seem to indicate a more fundamental problem with the system: either the people who care about tagging don't have the ability to do it, or the people who *can* do it aren't. Either way, asking people not to flag when they see a problem they can't solve seems like sweeping it under the rug...

Comment: @Shog, Never looked at it that way. Very persuasive. I still feel that moderators shouldn't be doing the easy stuff for the new users, mostly because the newer users can get those privileges in time, and if it *should* be retagged then one of our tag-level users should do it.

Comment: FWIW: [there has been at least one outright complaint about too much mod-flagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58102/who-will-rid-mods-of-these-turbulent-users-who-flag-questions-inappropriately)...

Comment: @Shog is having Will on my side really a boon?

Comment: @devinb: I wouldn't have posted it if I thought it would help your argument... ;-P

Comment: @Shog Well, let me try to put it another way. If I was a moderator, and lord knows there are thousands of reasons why that should never happen, I would *gladly* do these things to help new users *while they learn to use the system correctly*. However, that is operating on an *outreach* basis, not on a "this is how it *should* work" basis.